# ActiveAdmin: How to override index controller action: undefined method `base' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I'm trying to override the index action of the ActiveAdmin controller for it to display results for the current_user instead of all results.

```
controller do
  def index
    @user_tasks = UserTask.where(:user_id => current_user.id).page(params[:page])
  end
end
```

When accessing ActiveAdmin, an exception in thrown:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `base' for nil:NilClass):
    1: render renderer_for(:index)
```

I'm using rails 3.1 and the latest ActiveAdmin version. `gem "activeadmin", :git => 'https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin.git'`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not required any more.

ActiveAdmin 0.4.4 now supports scoping queries without overriding this method.
please see here: http://activeadmin.info/docs/2-resource-customization.html#scoping_the_queries

> If your administrators have different access levels, you may sometimes
>   want to scope what they have access to. Assuming your User model has
>   the proper has_many relationships, you can simply scope the listings
>   and finders like so:

```
 ActiveAdmin.register Post do
     scope_to :current_user

     # or if the association doesn't have the default name.
     # scope_to :current_user, :association_method => :blog_posts
 end
```

Comment: just adding this important distinction: this insists that there is an association with the current_user. If the user model has no defined association to the current model, this isn't going to work. Neither will using scope_to with a block.

Answer (score 11):

I don't know why but

```
controller do
    def index
      index! do |format|
        @user_tasks = UserTask.where(:user_id => current_user.id).page(params[:page])
        format.html
      end
    end
end
```

did the trick.

Answer (score 3):

Let override the action like this:

```
controller do
  def scoped_collection
    # some stuffs
    super.where("type = ?", "good")
  end 

  # other stuffs
end
```

By this way, you also can run the export functions (to xml, csv, ...) normally with new collection that you have overridden.

In my test, it just works for where condition and scope, not for limit.

Refer from this: https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/642