# activeadmin custom render if

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, activeadmin

My below code

```
ActiveAdmin.register Question do
  belongs_to :topic, :optional => true

  controller do
    def index
      @topic = Topic.find_by_id params[:topic_id]
      if @topic
        @questions = @topic.questions
        render 'settings/questions/_by_admin', :layout => 'active_admin'
        return
      end
    end
  end
end
```

is throwing

```
 NoMethodError in Admin/questions#index
```

Showing

> /home/amol/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@xxx/gems/activeadmin-0.5.0/app/views/layouts/active_admin.html.arb
>   where line #1 raised:
>
> undefined method `base' for nil:NilClass

Extracted source (around line #1):

```
1: insert_tag view_factory.layout
```

any idea? whats happening here.
Stack trace is not pointing to any of my written code file.

What I want here is, if @topic is present then I want to render my view else the default one.

Comment: what will happen if `@topic` is nil?

Comment: default activeadmin index page *should* get rendered

Comment: yes, it should be based on above code. i just wanted to make sure, you  were aware of that :). so when you get the error? when @topic is nil or opposite?

Comment: all the time, when @topic in nil or a valid Topic object

Comment: this worked http://stackoverflow.com/a/9048911/477403, dont know how

Comment: i've seen that but did not answer the bang `!` sign after index :s

Answer (score 0):

I have this scenario working calling to `super` as the last line in the controller action.

Super will render the default view for you.